# AWS EKS Kubernetes error: unable to recognize policy: no matches for kind "policy" in version "v1beta1"

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-networkpolicy

**These are my APIs available in AWS EKS 1.17**

```
✦ ➜ k api-versions
admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
apps/v1
argoproj.io/v1alpha1
authentication.k8s.io/v1
authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
authorization.k8s.io/v1
authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
autoscaling/v1
autoscaling/v2beta1
autoscaling/v2beta2
batch/v1
batch/v1beta1
certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
coordination.k8s.io/v1
coordination.k8s.io/v1beta1
crd.k8s.amazonaws.com/v1alpha1
discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1
events.k8s.io/v1beta1
extensions/v1beta1
metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1
networking.k8s.io/v1
networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
node.k8s.io/v1beta1
policy/v1beta1
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
scheduling.k8s.io/v1
scheduling.k8s.io/v1beta1
storage.k8s.io/v1
storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
v1
```

**this is my policy.yaml file**

```
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: policy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-egress
  namespace: edna
spec:
  order: 999
  egress:
  - action: deny
    destination:
      net: 35.162.205.100
    source: {}
```

**When I try to apply it I get the following:**

```
error: unable to recognize "app/base/backend/policies/deny-policy.yaml": no matches for kind "policy" in version "v1beta1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `api/v1beta1` when defining network policies , Also the kind in that case would be NetworkPolicy. I think this is what you should use.

The version `policy/v1beta1` is for defining poddisruptionbudget.

The kind Policy is used for defining audit policy and version
`audit.k8s.io/v1` and since this is not available in your output you cannot use this and hence the error.

[Here](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-apiversion-definition-guide.html)s a document that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to define a network policy.

In k8s documentation you can find several examples regarding [networking policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/)
and every one of these examples is using:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
```

I have also noticed that the yaml file content you provided is not valid.
Please refer to the networking policies documentation mentioned earlier or [k8s api referece guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18) for more detailed description of k8s yaml fields.